# Angular 4 HTTP Call to node Method, Making my object undefine

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient

Is there any way to make a HTTP Call from Angular 4 and fetch the JSON Response without using subscribe()??.

Comment: It would be really helpful to see your code. However, the answer to your question is no

Comment: Not if you use angular's HttpClient. You have to call subscribe, that's the way cold observables work. Why would you not want to ? Otherwise, you can use a normal xhr request

Comment: I guess it's all about the context that is not easy to manage when you are in the closure. You can't go against the flow, which means no to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, instead of `subscribe()` use `toPromise()`:

```
import { toPromise } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get(url).pipe(toPromise()).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

But there is no real difference between this or `subscribe()`, because the http call is an observable which completes after emitting. Which means there is also no need to unsubscribe

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want/need to use observables you can also try `async/await` way, example:

```
public async fetchData(): Promise<any> {
 try {
    const response = await this.http.get(url).toPromise();
    const data = data.json();
    // bind you component properties by accessing data object
    this.userName = data.name;
 } catch(e) {
   // error handling 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `publish` and `connect` from rxjs (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/publish.html)

```
this.http.get(url)
    .publish()
    .connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that without calling subscribe in typescript code. Instead do that using ***async*** pipe.

```
data$ : Observable<T>;

ngOnInit() {
this.data$ = this.service.get(); //which returns observable
}
```

Then, in template side.

```
<div *ngFor="let dummy of data | async" > {{ dummy }}</div>
```